# Pass argument to an instance of a class to implicitely call a method

Tags: python, class, apply

I recently saw something like this in a python library (PyTorch):

```
class A(BaseClass):
      def __init__(self,b,c):
           self.b =b 
           self.c = c
      def forward(self,d,e):
         return self.b + self.c + d + e

a_instance = A(1,2)
assert a_instance(d=4,e=5) == a_instance.forward(4,5)
```

where instead of directly calling the method "forward" inside the Class A, you can just pass the arguments to an instance of the class and under the hood it passes them to the "forward" function and calls it.

I very much like to know how to implement something like this.
 Any explanation to shed a light on this is very much appreciated.

PS: This is my made up example not the real thing.

Comment: This looks fishy to me.  What is `BaseClass`?  And don't you mean `class` rather than `Class`, and `__init__` rather than `__ini__`?  Also, `__ini__` is missing a colon on its `def` line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use __call__ method.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self,b,c):
        self.b =b 
        self.c = c
    def forward(self,d,e):
        return self.b + self.c + d + e

    def __call__(self,d,e):
        return self.forward(d,e)
a_instance = A(1,2)
assert a_instance(d=4,e=5) == a_instance.forward(4,5)
```

Comment: It is indeed much easier than what I thought. Thanks. Also a link for anyone who wants to read more about __call__: http://hplgit.github.io/primer.html/doc/pub/class/._class-solarized003.html

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how `BaseClass` is defined. For example in a regular situation you would have something as follows:

```
>>> class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
>>> B("sa")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#85>", line 1, in <module>
    B("sa")
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

If someone defined `BaseClass` as a metaclass though you would have a situation similar to this:
```

```
>>> class CallableClass(type):
    def __new__(self, a):
        print "Look at me, making life harder for everyone: "+str(a)


>>> class B(CallableClass):
    def __init__(self):
        pass


>>> B("Do I really need to?")
Look at me, making life harder for everyone: Do I really need to?
```

```

To get what you want you would do something like

```
>>> class CallableClass(type):
    def __new__(self, a):
        print "Look at me, making life harder for everyone: "+str(a)
        self.a = a
        return self


>>> class B(CallableClass):
    def __init__(self):
        pass


>>> a = B("Do I really need to?")
Look at me, making life harder for everyone: Do I really need to?
>>> a.a
'Do I really need to?'
```

but as my example exemplifies: why? 9/10 times you don't really need `metaclasses` and you really really, `really`, don't want them mixed up with your work - it's hard to debug, it's hard to write, it's hard to think about. Maybe this is an `xyz` question?

---

EDIT:

```
>>> class IsCallable(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("this is init")
    def __call__(self):
        print("this is call")

>>> class C(IsCallable):
    def __init__(self):
        IsCallable.__init__(self)
        pass
>>> C()
this is init
<__main__.C object at 0x7f32b98ebdd0>
>>> C()()
this is init
this is call
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you very much and thanks for the tip. Perhaps not use it in production. Was just curious.

Comment: A lot of general codes do this very same trick. Especiallydatabase systems (think in lines of ORMs). It's not a bad thing to use - as long as you're sure that's what you need. In 9/10 cases, it's not the thing you need though. I've added additional example showcasing how `__call__` is not `__init__` or even `__new__`. If what you wanted is just  way to do fancy syntax i.e. `B(whatever)` then `call` is what you need. Be forewarned - this is not the usual behavior and users don't expect it to exist. Consider `factory` approach instead, i.e. `B.fromFile`. Notice it's class `B` not object `B()`